# cellForRowAtIndexPath method custom button show 2 time

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, ios8

I used this code in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method. When I click on button or scroll table this button is shown two times. Why is this button shown 2 times please help me?

```
UIButton *trashbtn=[[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(cell.frame.size.width-20, cell.frame.size.height-30, 20, 20)];
[trashbtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"editor_trash"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[trashbtn addTarget:self action:@selector(DeleteMyAssociate:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[trashbtn setTag:indexPath.row];
[cell addSubview:trashbtn];
```

Answer (score 0):

You should firstly add a UITableViewCell within your table in IB. Then give an identifier e.g. "MyCellIdentifier" to that cell. Still on IB, add your outlets, to that cell e.g. the button, the textFields... You can initially set the button to be invisible. Then in the method cellForRowAtIndexPath, you do:

```
- (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyCellIdentifier"];
    if(cell){
        myButton.hidden = NO; // 
        myTextField.text = @"BlaBlaBla";
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a really old method for getting cells. If you use the `
- dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:` method and you have either correctly registered the cell identifier, or created the cell in a storyboard, then it will _always_ return a cell, so there is no need to check if the returned cell is nil or not.

Comment: The fact that I check for the cell is not nil, it doesn't mean that it's an old method. If you make a disaster on the IB file, you will trap it. My apps are very robust because I make them that way.

Comment: I use this in cellforrowAtIndexPath method    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"CustomCell";
    
    CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
   
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }

Comment: @Leonardo How is using a method that "always" returns a cell not robust? If your nib file doesn't have the correct cell identifier, you will still get a crash. Also - I run unit tests to check for this which makes my code robust.

Comment: @Abizern - As stated on the documentation for dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: "If no cell is available for reuse and you did not register a class or nib file, this method returns nil."

Comment: @Leonardo Look at the method I recommended in my comment, it has an indexPath parameter. Look at the documentation for this - it always returns a valid cell.

Comment: @Abizern - which is not the method I suggested. So, in my method I check for the nil case. I'm right. The method you use is meant for different cell styles at different rows.

Comment: @Leonardo Sir, if i use this button coding in  if (cell == nil) {  }else{ Here code for button} then first visible cell not show button and when i scroll table then every cell show button .

Comment: @Leonardo You're completely missing my point. I'll leave you to it.

Comment: @LC Nagar - If the cell is nil it means that you forgot to register the cell class (if you subclassed that cell) or the identifier is wrong... So you have to fix your code or the IB file. Otherwise the cell should never be nil. As stated in the docs: "This method dequeues an existing cell if one is available or creates a new one using the class or nib file you previously registered". So if your IB file is ok and you used an existing cellIdentifier you are ok. You could get nil if you set the cellIdentifier programmatically, e.g. cellStyle_08 and you end up with a non existing cellIdentifier

Answer (score 0):

Hey I can give you a suggestion that use auto layout and storyboard to add button rather than adding it programmatically. 
That is more better and cleaner approach.

Comment: If it's a suggestion, this is probably better as a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"CustomCell";
    
    CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
   
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }
i use this after that i want to add a button on cell.

Comment: Since you have already created a xib file for your cell so it will be better if you add the button in that xib file only.

Comment: @AkshayAgrawal , Sir i can do this but i use this cell me many diffrent-2 tables and each table require diffrent-2 action Button on cell.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are facing is that cells are reused in tableviews, So the first time you create a button and add it to the cell, it appears once. But if it is dequeued, it already has the button, so when you add another one you end up with multiple buttons.

There are two ways to correct this.

Firstly, remove the button in the cell's `prepareForReuse` method, which is called just after the cell is reused.

Secondly, avoid creating custom views in the `cellForTableView...` method. Use a custom cell that already has the button. Now, you may ask, how do I hook up the action for the button if I do it this way? You can either provide a delegate method for your cell that calls back to your view controller, or you can pass your cell a block to perform when the button is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

as far as i can get u already have a custom cell.. add a button to existing cell and create an IbOutlet for the same in customCell.h file
then in cellForRowAtIndexPath method access the button using its IBOutlet

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
   {

    customCell *cell =(customCell*) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"customCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    [cell.btn setTitle:@"blabla" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [cell.btn setTag:indexPath.row];
    [cell.btn addTarget:self action:@selector(method:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    if(condition)
     {
     cell.btn.hidden=YES;
     }
     else
     {
     cell.btn.hidden = NO;
     }
   return cell;
}
```

Do not forget to register for the customCell class in your ViewController class
                                                                              [tableName registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"customCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"customCell"];

you can hide or unhide the button as per your requirements as well as add different actions to the button in each class.
Happy Coding..!!

Do vote it if my code was helpful for you.. ;)